# Visual Studio 2012: How to handle code replacement over multiple lines

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I often have to replace multiple lines in multiple documents. In Visual Studio 2012 there seems to be the possibility to put muliple line code in a simple one-line-input-box only.

[image: search/replace box layer in Visual Studio 2012 (german language pack)]

In the "embedded" search box there is also only a single-line input field:
[image: embedded search/replace box in Visual Studio 2012 (german language pack)]

After inserting the often very long search terms and trying to put a regular expressions for line breaks into it, i have to move horizontally inside a one-line-input-field which isn't comfortable at all.

Is there another way to use the find/replace functionality for replacing muliple lines in Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: I doubt it. There hasn't been on any previous version of Visual Studio. For all the times you need to use multiple-line blocks of text, why don't you just use the larger dialog? (See also [here](http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/15) for a macro-based solution that gives you a custom find/replace dialog.)

Comment: In the meantime someone recommended me this (seems to be more UX-friendly than using RegEx): http://www.helixoft.com/blog/multiline-search-and-replace-in-visual-studio-2013-2005.html

Answer (score 10):

In order to replace multiple lines first you have to check regular expression option on search window. In following example it's search the

```
   first
   second
   third
```

and replace it with

```
  fourth
  fifth
  sixth
```

search text : first([\s\n]*)second([\s\n]*)third

replace text : fourth$1fifth$2sixth

[image: find replace example]

Comment: This helped me to replace one line with many by capturing the new line at the end and using it several times in the `Replace with` string.

Answer (score 0):

This worked exceptionally well for me:

http://vlasovstudio.com/sync-block-edit/